# python setup.py install syntax error

Tags: python

I am new to python and am trying to do web scraping, but I keep getting a syntax error every time I try to install a library.
I have tried installing both mechanize and mechanoid.
I change the directory using:

```
import os

os.chdir(path)
```

and then I do:

```
python setup.py install
```

but it keeps saying

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?
I am using Python 3.1.3

Comment: What does the first part have to do with the second part? If you're trying to install stuff, it's from the regular command line. The first part with the `import os` is in a python shell. The second with the `python setup.py install` is something you're supposed to type on the command line.

Comment: You're leaving out a bunch of stuff from the SyntaxError. Include the traceback that shows which line, etc. that the SyntaxError occured.

Answer (score 1):

`python setup.py install` is not python code & should be done from the command prompt in the directories you have extracted the mechanize and mechanoid libraries to and not from the python interpreter that you ran the change directory python code in.